# Database is not connected from webconfig file

Tags: asp.net, sqlconnection

The below code is during page load event in `aspx.cs` file. When I load the page in chrome, it throws some error in `cs` file.

**Stack trace error:Network related error while connecting to sql server:**

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        listviewmain.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Connection string in `web.config` file:**

```
<add name="constr"
             connectionString = "data source=.;initial catalog=[Analyst_RealEstate_WebCP];persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=pass@word1;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Sql Connection :

[image: Sql Connection image]

When I am trying to connect in `sql` using these credentials, I am able to login but not through `web.config` file

Comment: Your connection string is saying `Data Source=.` but when you login via SSMS the IP address is `67.205.112.199`. And the error message says it can't find the server on the network. Clearly your connection string needs to accurately point to where your database server is.

Comment: in future please paste error messages in directly, don't show screenshots of them, it's far more useful for people searching in future. But mason is right, this is simply a case that you haven't put the IP or hostname of your datasource into the connection string: `data source=.` should probably be `data source=67.205.112.199`

Comment: Isn't the '.', 'localhost' and the IP the same thing when we're talking about local sql instance?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev I've never heard of that, but maybe so, I don't know. But anyway how's it relevant? He's not trying to connect to locahost, in the screenshot he's connecting to some other IP address.

Comment: @ADyson how would you know that this is not the IP of localhost? :)

Comment: @DimitarTsonev I can't be 100% sure of course, but since a) most people don't bother typing a whole IP when they could just type localhost, and b) even if it is localhost, then using the "." clearly isn't working, it seems unlikely. That appears to be the only difference between the successful and failed connections. Perhaps sreeja can clarify if they have tried changing the IP in the web.config yet, and what the result is?

Comment: I added datasource='67.205.112.199' but still same erroris showing

Comment: try changing `datasource='67.205.112.199'` to `Server=67.205.112.199`. Note the lack of single quotes. This is as per docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx - Data Source is apparently only if you connect to a named instance.

Comment: I changed from datasource=67.205.112.199 to Server=67.205.112.199 but still same error.